# MSO Conditionals - !mso failing?

Tags: outlook, zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm working with some email template design for my company and leveraging off of the Zurb Foundation for Email framework (http://foundation.zurb.com/emails).   So far, I've been impressed with it.

The issue that I am having is with an column background that will have different text in it depending on the recipient (dynamic).    The background is basically a rounded "button" shape with a transparent "Arrow" on the right hand side.  Long story short - I was able to design this so it looked "good"  in modern email clients using some tables with some basic CSS.

The issue with this was that my CSS uses "border-radius" and outlook doesn't support that.    I found a workaround to this and "simplified"  the design for outlook specifically and use the MSO conditional to fire off this simplified design when appropreate.    The issue is that it ALWAYS seems to fire - no matter what email client I am using. . . (iPhone, gMail, etc).   I think something has to be wrong with the way I am setting up the conditional.

```
<table class="row center">
<tr>
    <td class="wrapper last panel">
        <!--[if mso]>
        <table class="twelve columns">
            <tr>
                <td class="one sub-columns">
                    Gift Code:
                </td>
                <td class="eleven sub-columns">
                  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:40px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:500px;" arcsize="20%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#faa21a">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
                        ZZ1234567890ABCD
                    </center>
                  </v:roundrect>
                </td>       
                <td class="expander"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !mso]>
        <!-- -->
        <table class="twelve columns" style="mso-hide:all;">
            <tr>
                <td class="one sub-columns">
                    Gift Code:
                </td>
                <td class="nine sub-columns promoCalloutInner alOrangeBg" style="mso-hide:all;">
                    ZZ1234567890ABCD
                </td>
                <td class="four sub-columns alOrangeBg promoCalloutInnerEnd" style="mso-hide:all;">
                    <img src="http://mcbain.gamelogic.com/~rdesroches/ALCEmailTemplates/images/transparentArrow.png" />
                </td>
                <td class="expander"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using the Zurb Inliner tool (http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html) to inline all the styles from my CSS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your non-Outlook conditional content (`<!--[if !mso]>`) isn't closing correctly.

Try this and let me know how you get on

```
<table class="row center">
<tr>
    <td class="wrapper last panel">
        <!--[if mso]>
        <table class="twelve columns">
            <tr>
                <td class="one sub-columns">
                    Gift Code:
                </td>
                <td class="eleven sub-columns">
                  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:40px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:500px;" arcsize="20%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#faa21a">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
                        ZZ1234567890ABCD
                    </center>
                  </v:roundrect>
                </td>       
                <td class="expander"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <table class="twelve columns" style="mso-hide:all;">
            <tr>
                <td class="one sub-columns">
                    Gift Code:
                </td>
                <td class="nine sub-columns promoCalloutInner alOrangeBg" style="mso-hide:all;">
                    ZZ1234567890ABCD
                </td>
                <td class="four sub-columns alOrangeBg promoCalloutInnerEnd" style="mso-hide:all;">
                    <img src="http://mcbain.gamelogic.com/~rdesroches/ALCEmailTemplates/images/transparentArrow.png" />
                </td>
                <td class="expander"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I changed:

```
<!--[if !mso]>
        <!-- -->
```

to

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
```

and

```
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

to

```
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like that made a difference.   The outlook code still always fires.   The only time it doesn't is when I preview the email in a standard browser.

Comment: And if you add a little more specificity to the Outlook conditional content, e.g. '<!--[if gte mso 9]>' does that make any difference? Also can you provide screenshots or tell me exactly which version/platform you're seeing the issue on.

Comment: OK, figured out part of my problem.  I was sending the email via Outlook, which had to magically removed the non-MSO stuff.    If I sent the email via Gmail,  the image comes through . . . 

However, when I open the gmail created version in Outlook, I see the image stuff. . . . I am wondering if the email client itself is stripping some code out before sending.