# Conditional comments in outlook365 (Win10)

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

As known Outlook client (Win version) doesn't use div's so I have to use tables. In order to make responsive design, I'm trying to use the hybrid design (as mentioned here https://www.litmus.com/blog/mobile-responsive-email-stacking/)

The problem is that the outlook client (outlook365 on win10) just ignores every syntax of conditional comments, and gives me the same results as if it was Gmail.
I couldn't find any answer. Could it be that Microsoft just removed this feature from their mail client? or am I doing something wrong.

I'll appreciate any idea. Thank you.

This is the HTML I've sent to myself and I got only the lines saying "this is not mso"  (both conditions were ignored (the positive and the negative).

```
<!--[if mso]>
this is mso
<![endif]-->
    
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 gte mso 9
<![endif]-->

    
<!--[if gte mso 16]>
this is mso 16 
<![endif]-->
    
    
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 gte mso 9
<![endif]-->


<!--[if !((gte mso 9)|(IE))]><!-- -->
 This is not mso 9\ie
<!--<![endif]-->


<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    This is not mso
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That code works as expected for me via Litmus (the first four conditionals show up on Outlook 365 windows 10). You're not talking about Outlook.com are you?

Comment: No. On the web version it's working on another engine so it looks just like in Chrome/Gmail.  The problem is with the Outlook client. The problem is that outlook does not have a debugging console so I only have the final display and I don't know what went wrong. That's why I made this simple debugging code for the conditions. For me it didn't worked out, and Outlook acted like it's not mso. I've tried on another computer (same Outlook365/win10 client) and got the same results.

Comment: And yes, the Litmus preview gives the right answer, the problem is that in the real Outlook client it just isn't working.

Comment: Weird. What's the specific build/version information for this particular setup?

Comment: Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20158) 64-bit

Comment: Hmm I've got nothing for you sorry. Can't replicate it. I believe you can see the output code via https://testi.at/ too, for another testing service that may or may not show it. For showing the altered code in your own machine, you can sort of get it by forwarding the test to yourself and then viewing the source of that forward.

Comment: This recent thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935901/html-email-mso-conditional-trick/70937664#70937664

Comment: Just came across this comment that might help us----how are you sending the email? If it's via Outlook, that might be stripping the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588751/mso-conditionals-mso-failing?rq=1#comment59269166_35743088

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem - Automated litmus testing shows everything rendering fine, but we had outlook 365 on an actual win10 machine ignoring MSO conditionals just like reported in this thread. Turns out the problem is with a toggle in the top right corner of outlook. "Try the new outlook" can be toggled off and that will restore the correct handling of MSO conditionals.

The core of the problem is that

1. We made VML buttons for outlook as regular buttons would not style correctly
2. This new experimental Outlook 365 ignores MSO, but still doesn't style the buttons correctly

So at the moment I do not have a solution for anyone who has the "try the new outlook" toggle turned on. The style declarations seems to be ignored on my HTML buttons and the VML buttons made for outlook are not being shown.

Still searching for a solution