# mso-hide:all does hide content but the taken space is still there in Outlook Desktop

Tags: html, email, outlook, ms-word, html-email

I am trying to solve the issues my email has with Outlook Desktop.
I tried things and eventually I was able to hide the part I want with conditional mso css and mso-hide:all. But the issue is that the space elements normally have when they are supposed to be appear is still taken.

What am I supposed to do if Outlook does not support `display:none` attribute and I have no option to write a different table for only Outlook?

Here is my css class to use only on Outlook Desktop:

```
<!--[if mso ]>
      <style>

         .mso-table{
            mso-hide:all;
            display:none;
            width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left;
            font-size:0;
            max-height:0;
            line-height:0;
         }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

I am using it and assign `mso-table` class to the tables I want to hide.

Comment: Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Why is this? "I have no option to write a different table for only Outlook". Why can't you use conditional code, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935901/html-email-mso-conditional-trick

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the entire table you want to hide on outlook with

```
<!--[if !mso]>-->
    HIDDEN TABLE HERE
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post now but figured I use this enough to share with hopes this can help others. This is super helpful when needing to use 2 different images for mobile and desktop while developing emails.

```
<img src="dog-desktop.png" class="desktop-only">

<!--[if !mso]>-->
<img src="dog-mobile.png" class="mobile-only">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I give whatever element that needs to be hidden a class that display: none; on desktop and then display: block; on mobile and vice versa for desktop.

Hopefully this helps anyone.